# How should the BaseAdapter coding programmatically without a layout file?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-arrayadapter, baseadapter, layout-inflater

There is a sample baseadapter as follows and it uses a layout xml file names adapter_layout. But I do not want to use the adapter_layout.xml. I want to identify with all components(TextView, EditText ...) in the class. How should the BaseAdapter coding programmatically without adapter_layout.xml?

```
public class LayoutAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private List<String> objects = new ArrayList<String>();

private Context context;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public LayoutAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return objects.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return objects.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_layout, null);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.textView2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        viewHolder.textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        viewHolder.editText1 = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    return convertView;
}


protected class ViewHolder {
    private TextView textView2;
    private TextView textView1;
    private EditText editText1;
}
```

}

Comment: Create Linear layout object(for example) and add your views in it.

Comment: How do I create it in baseAdapter, give me an example please.

Comment: You can do this with code as well, only need to do is you need to return your view instead of convert view and need to give number of times you want to show that data.